# Mainactivity overlapping fragment in android

Tags: android

Whenever I click the Receive message it goes to the ReceivedFragment and it works but the problem is the Mainactivity overlap the ReceivedFragment as you can see in the image below, I've already tried remove all views in the framelayout but the result is always the same, Can anyone help me? Im new in android  ,below is my current code, thanks

[image]

> MainActivty.java

```
           @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ReceivedFragment dashfragment = new ReceivedFragment();
                    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
                    fl.removeAllViews();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction1 =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction1.add(R.id.frame_layout, dashfragment);
                    transaction1.commit();
                    break;
                    //case - so on and so on
```

> My activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Try to hide and show listview and frame layout

Comment: I don't know how to implement it  , can you elaborate please ,can you help me? Im stuck with this module @MD

Comment: Hide the list when you show the fragment. 
For best practice, create another fragment to display that listView. so that the MainActivity has only one responsibility: manage the fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a reference to your `listView` in your `onCreate()` method.

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

in your `onItemClick` method:

```
listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Make it visible again when you go back:

```
listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add White or any background to Your fragment. That should fix the issue. This is happening because you are maintaining a stack of opened fragment.